# Dynamically add views to tablerow

Tags: android, android-layout, tablelayout

guys
I am wondering about the lenght of a table row.

In my application, views are dynamically created and added to tablelayout...and it gives no problems.

However, if the length of row is longger than the width of screen(since too many views are contained on the row), I can't see some of views on screen.

Do you know how to check it in prior to actually display the row on screen?

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the tableRow attributes and change the height and width of it dynamically

```
TableRow tableRow = findViewById(R.id.tableRow1);
tableRow.setMinimumHeight(minHeight);
tableRow.setMinimumWidth(minWidth);
tableRow.setWeightSum(weightSum);
```